# How to put buttons on each cell of a TableViewController in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am coding an iPhone App using Xcode and need some help using a TableViewController. I have a TableViewController with a list of names on it(contacts from a users phone) and I would like to implement buttons on each cell that has a name in it.

This button when clicked should move the name associated with it into another TableViewController.

If anyone knows how to simply get buttons into each cell of a TableViewController that would be great.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom *tableViewCell* where you can define a button as a property.

Also this cell should define protocol with one delegate method which will transfer click button action to the *tableViewController*.

Then in *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* you can set name for buttons in cells.

Also in the *tableViewController* you need to implement real action of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, select the prototype cell, set the style to 'custom'

[image]

Step 2, drag a button into the cell